# Fluent NHibernate - filter with connecting table not working

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I got following Table:

```
Public Class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Public Class Password {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PasswordText { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public string ModifyUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

I also got a connection table called: Password_User

Now I want to filter all Passwords after the Id from the Category. The Id I get from my Frontend-Code which is working (I get the right Id). I actually tried something but my problem is that the list is always the same.

Here my example:

```
if (categoryFilter > 1) {
   var PasswordEntity = _pagedDataQueryProcessor.GetDefaultQuery<Data.Entities.Password>();
   _pagedByIdDataQueryProcessor.GetById<Data.Entities.Password>(categoryFilter);

   PasswordEntity.Where(
       Restrictions.Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.Categories).IsLike(categoryFilter))
       );
}
```

The if at the start is there because I didn't have a Category with the Id 1 because I use the list more than at one place and i maked it in the frontend where i gave a Category the Id 1 and a Name.

When you need more Information than say it.

Can someone help me that I don't get always the full list. I want the list which is filtered.

Answer (score 0):

`PasswordEntity` will contain a collection of all `Password` entities because you're not capturing the filtered collection returned by your call to the `Where` method.